# Grading and Hilbert's syzygy theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Hilbert's syzygy theorem is usually stated in one of the following forms. Let $A = k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ and $k$ be a field.

1. Every finitely generated $A$-module has a free resolution of length at most $n$.
2. Every finitely generated *graded* $A$-module as a *graded* free resolution of length at most $n$.

Here, “graded” refers to the usual $\mathbf{Z}$-grading. However, what if I consider $\mathbf{Z}^n$-graded modules? I assume the statement is still true.

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $\mathbf{Z}^n$-graded $A$-module. Then it is also a $\mathbf{Z}$-graded $A$-module, so it has a $\mathbf{Z}$-graded free resolution $F_\bullet$ of length at most $n$. It is not clear, however, that $F_\bullet$ is a resolution of $\mathbf{Z}^n$-graded modules.

The first two paragraphs in [this text](https://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/wbruns/brunsw/pdf-article/BrunsHerzog_1995.pdf) seem to imply that $\mathbf{Z}^n$-homogeneous bases for $F_\bullet$ can be chosen such that all entries in the corresponding matrices are monomials, which would imply that $F_\bullet$ is a resolution of $\mathbf{Z}^n$-graded modules.

I am convinced the statement is true; however, I am wondering if one has to go through the proofs of the $\mathbf{Z}$-graded statement and verify everything works also in the $\mathbf{Z}^n$-grade case, or if the statement can be derived from the $\mathbf{Z}$-graded one.